# What use to make reminder app?

Tags: android, background, reminders

I want to write reminder. What i need to use? Make service app or just standart app runing in background or another way?

Thanks for replys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I really liked about this question is you asked about the idea for the app that you want to implement. You didn't ask for code.

I would suggest that you should make an app which should have a broadcast receiver, but still it should have service that runs in background.

The service will check the current time with your reminder time. A broadcast receiver is required to listen to startup broadcast, because you need to start your app as soon as your handset starts.

[Have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896908/keep-service-running-even-if-the-phone-is-switched-off/4897882#4897882).

Comment: Thanks! I have good experience with android development and all needed tutorials exists in android developter site. I just want to know best way of reminder app!

Comment: hmm nice i have also added one link to that have a look at it. it is also for reminder....

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). It allows you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future.